# A function that has a derivative but is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How is it possible that the function $F(x)$ defined by :

$$ 
     F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} x\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}, & x> 0 \\
         0, & x=0\end{array}\right. 
$$

$$ 
     F'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos\frac{1}{x}, & x> 0 \\
         0, & x=0\end{array}\right. 
$$

has a derivative, which  is not *Riemann- integrable* on any interval $[0,|b|]$, the function is continuous and every continuous function should have a R-Integral?

Comment: Are you claiming that $F(x)$ is not Riemann integrable, or that $F'(x)$ is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: When you say integrable, do you mean it has a finite value?

Comment: $F$ certainly is Riemann integrable, but $F'$ is not, as it's unbounded on $[0,|b|]$. This is probably an example of a function (namely $F'$)  having a primitive but failing to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes, it was meant for the derivative

Comment: @bakabakabaka: I'm still confused.  You wrote "the function is continuous and every continuous function should have a R-Integral".  You found $F'$ to be continuous on $[0,|b|]$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer yes, i think F' is continuous because for x=0 it is 0, how do you see that it is unbounded ?

Comment: Take $x=1/(2n\pi)$ with $n$ *big*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability states that a function $f: [a, b] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

In the present case, $|F(x)| \leq |b| \sqrt{|b|}$ on $[0, |b|]$ and $F$ is also continuous on $[0, |b|]$, so by Lebesgue's criterion $F$ is Riemann integrable.

On the other hand, $F'$ is not bounded in any neighborhood of $x = 0$, so by Lebesgue's criterion it is *not* Riemann integrable.

The point of this example is that you can't always integrate a function just because that function is a derivative of some other function.