# Re-statement of Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The Fundamental theorem of calculus states:

$f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that $ \forall x\in\left(a,b\right)$ $F'\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$, then $\int_{a}^{b}f=F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)$.

Can we rewrite it without using $f$ explicitly. For example,

$F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b}F'=F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)$.

If yes, then why mathematician introduced $f$?

If no, could you provide a counterexample that would illustrates the shortcomings of the re-statement.

Comment: The shortcoming of the re-statement is that it is not the statement we are used to. If you ask me, wriring the $f$ explicitly helps me to understand the theorem. I see no reason why your rewriting is any better than the original.

Comment: If $F'$ isn't continuous or more general a regulated function, taking the Riemann integral may not be defined.

Comment: @abcdef, could you provide an example, please?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293076/a-function-that-has-a-derivative-but-is-not-integrable

Comment: Or another example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function

Comment: @abcdef, thank you very much!